# using assign statement for `define statement

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am using assign statement of verilog for assigning `define as below in my driver module.

```
`define  SPI_MASTER_P_IF spi_vif.spi_master_p.spi_master_p_cb

`define SPI_MASTER_N_IF spi_vif.spi_master_n.spi_master_n_cb

`define SPI_MASTER_IF

class my_driver extends uvm_driver;

  assign `SPI_MASTER_IF = (if_posedge)?`SPI_MASTER_P_IF: `SPI_MASTER_N_IF;

endclass
```

When I compile I am facing the error as "near "assign": syntax error, unexpected assign, expecting function or task"

What is the proper way to do this assignment?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot define a macro using an `assign` statement. What you want here is `ifdef`:

```
`ifdef IF_POSEDGE
  `define SPI_MASTER_IF SPI_MASTER_P_IF
`else
  `define SPI_MASTER_IF SPI_MASTER_N_IF
`endif
```

See section 22.6 of the [1800-2012 standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The definition `SPI_MASTER_IF` is empty.
The code becomes:

```
assign = (if_posedge)?spi_vif.spi_master_p.spi_master_p_cb:spi_vif.spi_master_n.spi_master_n_cb
```

which is illegal.

Also `assign` might not be used there too,
please check the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 8.3 (class syntax) in the specification.

Comment: you are correct that `assign` cannot used in a `class`.

Comment: If it is to choose the clocking block to do something at runtime, perhaps it's better to use `fork...join`, and use `if([!]if_posedge)` in each process to run or not to run.